# loop over a subset of an enumeration in java

Tags: java, enums

I have got an enum prepared with 9 colors. But for a given run of the program I want to loop through the n first values. How would I do this in the best way. A problem I have is that I cant compare a Color with an int.

```
public enum Color{WHITE, YELLOW, GREEN, TEAL, BLUE, PURPLE, PINK, ORANGE, BLACK}
private int numberOfColorsToUse = 6;
```

the loop which doesn't work:

```
for(Game.Color color : Game.Color.values())
{
    if(!(color < numberOfColorsToUse))
        break;
    DrawRectangle(color);
}
```

EDIT: I read about ordinal(), but I "shouldn't need" to use it. What does this mean?

Comment: `<` will not compare an `int` to and `enum`

Comment: First of all , in your code you're missing a bracket ")" in the if condition : for(Game.Color color : Game.Color.values()) { if(!(color < numberOfColorsToUse)) break; DrawRectangle(color); }

Comment: Mel Nicholson: I know, that is why I asked this question.
Kafil10: edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If its always the first 6 colors, you can use the ordinal of an enum.

```
for(Game.Color color : Game.Color.values())
{
    if(!(color.ordinal() < numberOfColorsToUse))
        break;
    DrawRectangle(color);
}
```

A better way is to use a EnumSet to specify exactly the colours you want:

```
EnumSet.of(WHITE, YELLOW, GREEN, TEAL, BLUE, PURPLE);
```

To avoid strange behaviours when changing the ordering in the enum.

Or if you want a range:

```
EnumSet.range(WHITE,PURPLE) //has all elements from WHITE to PURPLE
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me about EnumSet. And if I want to save en EnumSet I use a Set<Game.Color> colorsToUse variable, correct?

Answer (score 3):

This is easily fixed by implementing your own counter.

```
int counter = 0;

for(Game.Color color : Game.Color.values())
{
    if(counter >= numCoulours)
        break;
    DrawRectangle(color);

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Of course, thanks :) Let's say I wanted to do this for an arbitrary subset, then I would likely creat a Color[] colorsToUse = {BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW} and loop over that instead, ok?

Comment: @Moberg In that case, you could put the colors in a `java.util.List`, and use the `contains` method to check if `color` is in the `colorsToUse` `List`.

Comment: EnumSet seems more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Introduce new counter and increase it in each iteration:

```
int i = 0;
for(Game.Color color : Game.Color.values())
{
    if(i++ >= numberOfColorsToUse)
        break;
    DrawRectangle(color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With enums, a much better approach is to use a "stop color" instead of a "stop index":

```
Color stop = PINK;

for(Game.Color color : Game.Color.values())
{
    if(color == stop)
        break;
    DrawRectangle(color);
}
```

Note: Enums are the only Java objects that are safe to compare with `==`.

But maybe a better approach would be to create another array with colors you want to iterate over:

```
private Color[] subset = Arrays.copyOfRange( Color.values(), 0, 6 );
```

Now you can iterate over the array. That said, this will cause odd problems when you start reordering the colors later for any reason. That why it's often better to name the colors you want to use:

```
private Color[] subset = { Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.TEAL, Color.BLUE, Color.PURPLE };
```

That way, it's clear which colors you will get.

Comment: Using a stop value is not runtime dynamic thought, correct? :)

Comment: The order of the enum value also can't change at runtime, so it doesn't matter. That said, you can also get the stop value with `Color.values()[6]`. The only problem here is that it breaks if you need all values. In this case, use the version with `copyOfRange()`

Comment: It matters because I want to change how many colors are used. Sometimes 4, sometimes 8.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing: either the `enum` *should* be `static`, or you *should* be referring to an instance of `Game`, not `Game` itself, to access the enumeration.
Although I might be wrong about that; after all, if it compiles, the class access stuff can't be all that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from counter approach, this one would also work if you can designate a number with `Color`:

```
void iterateFirstN(int n)
{
    Color[] vals = Color.values();
    for (Color v : vals)
    {
        if(v.num() >= n)
            break; //or return
    }
}

public enum Color {
    WHITE(1), YELLOW(2), GREEN(3), TEAL(4), BLUE(5), PURPLE(6), PINK(7), ORANGE(8), BLACK(9);

    int colorNum;
    Color(int num)
    {
        colorNum = num;
    }

    int num()
    {
        return colorNum;
    }

}
```